# C# - Copy rows from one DataTable by comparing with 2nd DataTable to 3rd DataTable

Tags: c#, linq

I have 4 `DataTables` in my C# code;

```
DataTable dt1;
DataTable dt2;
DataTable dt3;
DataTable dt4;
```

`dt1` has following records

```
Id | Name | City
----------------
1 | Abc | Khi
2 | XYZ | Hyd
3 | TVW | Lhr
4 | tyz | Isb
```

`dt2` has just ID records

```
Id
---
2
4
```

I need to copy only rows from `dt1` which are also available in `dt2` to `dt3`.  also required to store not matching records in 4th `dt4`

I found this but does not know how to copy to `datatable` properly and also how `not equals` works here

```
var matchingRows = from s1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                               join s2 in d2.AsEnumerable() on s1.Field<int>("Id") equals s2.Field<int>("Id")
                               select s1;
```

Comment: I can write code with `for`. is it good for you or just with linq?

Answer (score 2):

I do not like using var when it is not necessary.  You are loosing track of what you are actually doing.  mathcingRows is a List.  So the task is simple :

```
           List<DataRow> matchingRows = (from s1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                                          join s2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() on s1.Field<int>("Id") equals s2.Field<int>("Id")
                                          select s1).ToList();
            foreach (DataRow row in matchingRows)
            {
                dt4.Rows.Add(row);
            }
```

Comment: how to use `not equals` here

Comment: Use a left outer join.  See msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 2):

You can create two queries to find the matching and non-matching rows and then copy the rows into each answer `DataTable`:

```
var dt3 = dt1.Clone();
var dt4 = dt1.Clone();

var matchingRows = from s1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                   join s2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() on s1.Field<int>("Id") equals s2.Field<int>("Id")
                   select s1;

matchingRows.CopyToDataTable(dt3, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);

var nonMatchingRows = from s1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                      where !dt2.AsEnumerable().Any(s2 => s2.Field<int>("Id") == s1.Field<int>("Id"))
                      select s1;

nonMatchingRows.CopyToDataTable(dt4, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
```

If `dt2` has a large number of entries and performance is more important than memory, you could convert `dt2` to a `HashSet` to optimize the match testing:

```
var dt2hs = new HashSet<int>(dt2.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<int>("Id")));

var matchingRows = from s1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                   where dt2hs.Contains(s1.Field<int>("Id"))
                   select s1;

var nonMatchingRows = from s1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                      where !dt2hs.Contains(s1.Field<int>("Id"))
                      select s1;
```

Another performance option would be to just scan `dt1` once and then manually loop and select each destination:

```
var dt1jdt2 = from s1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
              join s2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() on s1.Field<int>("Id") equals s2.Field<int>("Id") into s2j
              from s2 in s2j.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new { s1, s2 };

foreach (var r in dt1jdt2) {
    if (r.s2 != null)
        dt3.Rows.Add(r.s1.ItemArray);
    else
        dt4.Rows.Add(r.s1.ItemArray);
}
```

Of course you can combine the `HashSet` and single scan options:

```
var dt2hs = new HashSet<int>(dt2.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<int>("Id")));

foreach (var s1 in dt1.AsEnumerable())
    if (dt2hs.Contains(s1.Field<int>("Id")))
        dt3.Rows.Add(s1.ItemArray);
    else
        dt4.Rows.Add(s1.ItemArray);
```